# r.body.find is not a function - snekfetch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to work with a game's API: the app fetches data from the API and shows it in the console but, when I try to show it in the Discord chat, it seems to fail to execute the `.find()` function.

I have tried to remove the `.find()` function and directly displaying the body of the result.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";
const token = "...";

const snekfetch = require("snekfetch");
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('This Bot Is online');
  bot.user.setActivity("Rainbow Six Siege", {
    type: "WATCHING"
  });
});

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'server') {
    message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
  } else if (command === 'detail') {
    if (!args.length) {
      return message.channel.send(`Correct Syntax : !details platform username`);
    } else if (args[0] === message.content) {

    }
    let name = `${args[1]}`;
    let plat = `${args[0]}`;
    const api = `https://someweb/api/search.php?platform=${plat}&search=${name}`;
    snekfetch.get(api).then(r => {
      let body = r.body;
      let entry = body.find(post => post.p_name === `${args[1]}`);
      if (!entry) return message.channel.send("error");
    });
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

My Console.log

```
{ results:
   [ { p_id: 'f2d8bf92-472a-4381-8b53-41eb374b0ca6',
       p_name: 'TR3STO',
       p_level: 68,
       p_platform: 'uplay',
       p_user: 'f2d8bf92-472a-4381-8b53-41eb374b0ca6',
       p_currentmmr: 374,
       p_currentrank: 1,
       verified: 0,
       kd: 59 } ],
  totalresults: 1 }
```

Comment: Does it return JSON? If so, have you tried `JSON.parse` ? what is `body` ?

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Add `console.log(r)` on the line before `let body = r.body;` and paste the resulting output into your question. *"I have tried to remove the .find() function and directly displaying the body of the result"* - Well then... what is it? :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You're using the [tag:discord.js] tag but the problem has nothing to do with it: the `.find()` method you're referring to is not from the library, it depends on what `r.body` is. With that said, I'll remove your question from the [tag:discord.js] tag. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I guess your body is an object and it does not have find method as array. can you console.log the body object

Comment: @ducmai just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for searching in result instead. edit your code as following may help

```
let entry = body.results.find(post => post.p_name === `${args[1]}`);
```

Comment: Thank You very much! It was so dumb of me that I was fetching the body of a body instead of fetching the result of the body :)